# How to select and subset rows based on sting in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe, text

My dataset looks like following. I am trying to subset my `pandas` dataframe such that only the responses by all 3 people will get selected. For example, in below data frame the responses that were answered by all 3 people were "I like to eat" and "You have nice day" . Thus only those should be subsetted. I am not sure how to achieve this in `Pandas` dataframe.

*Note:  I am new to Python ,please provide explanation with your code.*

**DataFrame example**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Person':['1', '1','1','2','2','2','2','3','3'],'Response':['I like to eat','You have nice day','My name is ','I like to eat','You have nice day','My name is','This is it','I like to eat','You have nice day'],
      }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Person           Response
0      1      I like to eat
1      1  You have nice day
2      1        My name is 
3      2      I like to eat
4      2  You have nice day
5      2         My name is
6      2         This is it
7      3      I like to eat
8      3  You have nice day
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC I am using `transform` with `nunique`

```
yourdf=df[df.groupby('Response').Person.transform('nunique')==df.Person.nunique()]
yourdf
Out[463]: 
  Person           Response
0      1      I like to eat
1      1  You have nice day
3      2      I like to eat
4      2  You have nice day
7      3      I like to eat
8      3  You have nice day
```

---

Method 2

```
df.groupby('Response').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(df['Person'].unique()).isin(x['Person']).all())
Out[467]: 
  Person           Response
0      1      I like to eat
1      1  You have nice day
3      2      I like to eat
4      2  You have nice day
7      3      I like to eat
8      3  You have nice day
```

Comment: Another question. How do I go about subsetting same response from another dataset ? Let's say I don't have Person column in that dataset. All I have is "Response" column

Comment: @biggboss2019 using isin like df2.loc[df2.response.isin(yourdf.response )]

Comment: Thank you, It was very useful to know isin() function